# How to insert the values using SparkSQL into Hive?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I amtrying to insert the values into Hive table using SparkSQL. I have values stored in a list and trying to insert using String.

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Spark + Hive + sentiment Analyzer")
                .master("local[*]")
                .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://localhost:9083")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
        spark.sql("create table if not exists output (srno int, values_string string)");
for(String str: nameAndCity){
            //System.out.println(str);
           str = str.replaceAll("\"","'");
             spark.sql("insert into output values(" + i +","+ "'"+ str+"'"+")");
            i++;
        }
```

I have strings containing `double quotes`, `single quotes`, and other characters. I tried to nullify the `double quote` but of now use.
I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spark.main(spark.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
17/03/04 16:55:50 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/03/04 16:55:50 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.0.15:4040
17/03/04 16:55:50 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/03/04 16:55:50 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
```

Kindly let me know what I should do to run my code flexibly? Kindly suggest me.
Input is like this:

```
Mary let you win.
"Pleasant day to play football"
Don't worry go home now.
We ---- Will have conversation with you for sure. Relax.
```

And many others

Comment: try using this:- spark.sql("insert into table output values(" + i +",'"+str+ "')"); If this does not solve your problem then please provide content in inameAndCity.

Comment: @AshishSingh Sure. I will write the input string here.